# Do hidden rooms spawn in the Abyss?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-blades

Jobs in Blades will tell you when a "Hidden Secret" is present in that quest. However, a loading screen tooltip about Secrets doesn't indicate that Secret Rooms are only found in certain quests/jobs. I don't often go into the Abyss, but does an Abyss Floor have a chance to spawn with a Secret Room?